# What is this 'wall box' port on my garage door opener?

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

The back of my Boss OL4 garage door opener has a square port with two pins labeled 'wall box' - see top of page 11 in the manual [here](https://www.steel-lineautomation.com.au/uploads/7/2/0/3/7203835/bol4.pdf).

Thing is there are also separate terminals for a push button to open/close, which I already use - so I don't understand what the wall box is for and how it's different.

Confusingly the manual doesn't actually mention what it does, and I'm unwilling to do too much probing in case I damage something.

Comment: I would *guess* that it might be for the "code pad" type of thing mounted **outside** the garage where you have to put in the right number/code to open it, but I don't *know* that.

Comment: See picture oin eBay:https://www.ebay.ca/itm/Guardian-3-Function-Wall-Button-Garage-Door-Deluxe-Wall-Console-Wall-Box-XP1/123532475695

Comment: Or one of those "doorbell-looking" push buttons....

Comment: Well.  Since they already have 4 standard screw terminals there, they could've easily just had six. ***They did not***, and swerved out of their way to have a weird custom socket that you can't use.  Which means, the company's intent is that you not use that socket except for company supplied equipment which uses it.

Comment: ...Which matters because of NEC 110.3(B) which requires that you install equipment according to the instructions.  Since UL approves the instructions as part of the UL listing, there may have been a hazard to someone hooking "any old thing" to those terminals, so UL may have told them "you must make it a weird plug".

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That looks promising, despite it being a different brand. If that's the case then it's communicating something more complex over a single wire (via PWM or voltage variance or something) with the light/lock etc, so they'd want to prevent idiots like me just shorting it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Quite a reasonable potential explanation of why it's a weird box, but I still want to know what it does. :)
You'd think you'd be able to just buy the part but I can't find it or any info really anywhere.

Comment: I would agree with ecnerwal, if the instructions don’t tell you it may be an option so why not contact the company and ask those that made it.